# JQuery AJAX won't display on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a form which selects & updates a SQL Table.

**JS:**

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
  function fetch_data()  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"select.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            cache:"false",
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#live_data').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  }  
  fetch_data();  

  function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"edit.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            cache:"false",
            data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#updatesucess').html(data);  
                  $('#updatesucess').delay(2000).fadeOut(300);
            }  
       });  
  }  
  $(document).on('blur', '.OilProd', function(){  
       var id = $(this).data("id2");  
       var OilProd = $(this).text();  
       edit_data(id, OilProd, "OilProd");  
    });  
  });  
 </script>
```

**Form:**

```
<html>  
  <head>  
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
       <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

  </head>  
  <body>  
       <div class="container">  
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <strong>Kodiak Daily Production
                    </strong>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">


            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <div id="updatesucess"></div>
                 <p></p>
                 <div id="live_data"></div>                 
            </div>  
       </div> <!-- close panel body --> 
       </div> <!-- panel panel-default -->
       </div> <!-- close col-lg-12 -->
       </div> <!-- close row --> 
       </div> <!-- Close Container --> 
  </body>  
</html>
```

The following code displays the contents of the php on Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE8/9.

I have tried the following

Set **cache:"false",**
 **async: false,**
changed from get to post but no go.

What else do I need to do to get this working in Internet Explorer 8-11 ???

**UPDATE:**

Added the following tag in HTML and now can atleast display data, but unable to make any edits on the form.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: may be javascript is disabled in your IE check and correct

Comment: java script is enabled.

Comment: Try alert(data) or console.log(data) on the data as the first line in the success{} block. I think that one of the jQuery functions may be failing on IE

Comment: What version of jQuery? jQuery 2.x dropped support for IE8.

Comment: Well i am running Ie11. Jquery Version 2.2.0

Comment: You say you need to get it running in IE8, so you will definitely need to downgrade jQuery to v1.x rather than v2. This shouldn't have any effect on how it works in IE11 though, so that's separate to the issue you're having now.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Internet Explorer sometimes has it's own life regarding cache. If you check the network tab in the Internet Explorer console, you will see a 304 status(not modified) for the ajax request. I have experienced this sometimes, and it seems like the request gets blocked by Internet Explorer and never reach the server.

You can try to solve the problem by adding a get parameter with a random number to the ajax function.

```
$.ajax({  
        url:"select.php?breakcache=" + Math.random(),  
        method:"POST",  
        cache:"false",
        success:function(data){  
             $('#live_data').html(data);  
        }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite running IE11 and specifying X-UA-Compatible, you should still check what rendering mode IE is using. In particular, check that it isn't using Quirks Mode, because this will definitely kill Ajax (and a lot of other features as well).

I suspect that this may be the problem because your HTML code doesn't include a DOCTYPE, and a missing doctype automatically makes IE jump into quirks mode.

Fix this problem by adding the HTML5 doctype to the top of your HTML file (immediately above the `<html>` tag):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Added the tag '<!DOCTYPE html>' but still no go.